# boundary operator of a sum singular homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[https://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/teaching/algtopI14/Lecture01.pdf](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Emgroth/teaching/algtopI14/Lecture01.pdf)

I am using the notations from this link. So, I have to calculate the boundary operator $\partial(\sum_{i=0}^{n} d_i^n)$ where $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$ simplex and $d_i: \Delta^{n-1} \mapsto \Delta^n$ is the face map.

I have two questions:

1. How I solved the problem: I used the fact that $\partial(\sum_{i=0}^{n} d_i^n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k d_i \circ d_k$ and then I used the formula that $d_i \circ d_k = d_k \circ d_{i-1}$ when $0 \le k < i \le n+1$. So I divided my sum to three parts: for $k \le i-1$, $k=i$ and $k \ge i+1$. I feel like the first and the third sum should cancel each other because of the relation I mentioned before:$d_i \circ d_k = d_k \circ d_{i-1}$ when $0 \le k < i \le n+1$. Is this right? Is there a way to write this rigorously?
2. Now, my second question is: I know that a singular $n$ simplex in $X$ is a continuous map $\sigma$ from $\Delta^n$ to $X$ where $X$ is a topological space. We can calculate $\partial(\sigma)$ using the alternating sum i.e. $\partial(\sigma)= \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \sigma \circ d_i$ where $d_i$ is the face map. Does this mean that in my problem, $X$ is $\Delta^n$ and we can consider $d_i$ itself as a singular $n$-simplex?  Is there a particular name for such $n$ simplex?

I am only familiar with singular homology, so I am not familiar with simiplicial homology or delta complex.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Is correct. $d_{i}^{n} \circ d_{j}^{n-1} = d_{j}^{n} \circ d_{i-1}^{n-1}: \Delta^{n-2} \rightarrow \Delta ^{n}$, $0 \leq j < i < n-1$, can be verified with direct calculation. I believe you have that as a lemma in the book "An introduction to homological algebra" Joseph J. Rotman.

(2) Yes. $\Delta^{n}$ is called "standard $n$-simplex".